# Concatenate rows to one column sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I have limited functionality on our current database. I have a scenario where I need to Concatenate rows to one column in SYBASE

```
LETTER
A
B
C
D

EXPECTED RESULT
A,B,C,D
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) and version? some of these products have functions to easily perform this operation, some don't so, we need to know which Sybase RDBMS product/version.

Comment: We're using ASE 15.7. I don't see any function would help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Sybase ASE does not provide support for list(), group_concant() nor FOR XML/PATH, so you'll need to write your own function; see [create function](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/CHDEDGJI.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this form ... change for you need!

```
declare @w_caracter_val varchar(2),
        @w_contador smallint,
        @w_registros smallint,
        @w_caracterFinal varchar(30)
--Crear tabla temporal        
create table #sb_caracteres   
             (se_id            int identity,
              codigo           varchar(10))
--insert a la tabla #                                
insert into #sb_caracteres
           (codigo)
    select  codigo        
     from cr_corresp_sib  
    where tabla = 'T260'   

--select * from #sb_caracteres
select @w_registros = (select count(1)from  #sb_caracteres)
select @w_contador = 1
select @w_caracterFinal= ''

while @w_contador <= @w_registros 
begin
    select   @w_caracter_val = codigo             
    from #sb_caracteres  
    where se_id = @w_contador

print 'codigo %1!, %2!',  @w_contador, @w_caracter_val

--select @w_caracterFinal= concat(@w_caracterFinal,@w_caracter_val)

select @w_caracterFinal = ltrim(rtrim(@w_caracterFinal)) + ltrim(rtrim(@w_caracter_val))   

select @w_caracterFinal
--print 'registros %1!',  @w_caracterFinal
Select @w_contador = @w_contador +1
end
```